# Open set or closed set in metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Example
>
> Let $X=\lbrace f\colon [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}\, |\, f \text{ is continuous on } [a,b]\rbrace$. Then $d(f,g)=\max_{x \in [a,b]}|f(x)-g(x)|$ for any $f,g \in X$ is a metric on $X$.

From the example, if $Y$ is the subset of $X$ containing all continuous functions $f$ on $[a,b]$ such that $f$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$. Is $Y$ an open set or a closed set of ($X,d)$ ?

Can anyone help me to answer my questions, I found an example in my notes then the question arises. Thank you.

Comment: I think the answer to that question is no. It is not open or closed.

Comment: can you explain the reason, why it is not open or closed ?

Comment: Well it's not open because its complement is dense, and it's not closed because it itself is also dense (I believe).

Comment: @MattSamuel $X\setminus Y$ is dense in $X$, but $Y$ is not dense in $X$ (it is actually of the first category, or meager, in $X$).

Comment: @Aweygan $Y$ is meagre but nonetheless dense. By Weierstraß' approximation theorem, the set of polynomial functions is dense in $X$.

Comment: The answer you accepted is totally wrong. Please consider accepting one of the other answers (both others are correct).

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

- To show that $Y$ is not closed, consider the sequence $\{f_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ such that each $f_n$ is defined over $[0,1]$, and 
  $$f_n(x)=\sqrt{\left(x-\frac 12\right)^2+\frac 1n}.$$
  Show that $f_n$ uniformly converges to the non-differentiable function
  $$f(x)=\left|x-\frac 12\right|.$$
- To show that $Y$ is not open, note that for the function $f(x)=x$ (defined over $[0,1]$) we have $f\in Y$, but for each $\epsilon<\frac 12$, the continuous but non-differentiable function
  $$g(x)=\begin{cases}(1-2\epsilon)x, &0\le x\le \frac 12\\(1+2\epsilon)x-2\epsilon, &\frac 12<x\le 1\end{cases}$$
  is always within $\epsilon$-distance of $f$.

Comment: it means $Y$ is not open set or closed set of topological space $(X,d)$ , right ?

Comment: @Ange Yes, it is neither closed nor open.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x)=0$ for $x\in [a,(a+b)/2]$ and $g(x)=|x-(a+b)/2|/(b-a).$

Then $kg\in X $ \ $Y$ for any $k\ne 0.$

If $f\in Y$ then for any $r>0$ the function $f+rg$ belongs to $B_d(f,r)$ \ $Y$. So $Y$ is not open.

Let $(b_n)_n$ be a sequence in $(a,(a+b)/2)$ converging to $(a+b)/2.$

Let $f_n(x)=0$ for $x\in [a, b_n].$

Let $f_n(x)=|x-(a+b)/2|$ for $x\in [a+b-b_n,b].$

Let $f_n(x)=(x-b_n)^2/(2(a+b-2b_n))$ for $x\in (b_n,a+b-b_n).$

We can easily verify that each $f_n\in Y$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty}d(f_n, (b-a)g)=0.$ But $(b-a)g\in X$ \ $Y$ . So $Y$ is not closed.

The idea of the $f_n$ is to "round off" the "corner" (at $x=(a+b)/2$) of the function $|x-(a+b)/2|.$